# Make a App wide progress bar (Across the pages of whole app) and manage its state as required in Flutter using provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, scoped-model

Im trying to make a Custom Progress Indicator widget which i can show or hide in any of the pages(Anywhere across the app). My approach is to bind a provider value for the progress widget and toggle the value as required. But I just don't get where exactly i should place the Progress/loader widget to make it work in whole App.

Or should i resort to using progress widget in each of the required pages and toggle it?

I'm coming from a web development background, so is there a equivalent of rootPage/ rootscreen where we can place app wide components (as in React, Ionic).